# how to get last date between two dates SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

For Example i have two Parameters of Date

```
first: 1/21/2016     
Second: 4/21/2017
```

I want to get second date.Is it possible through any SSRS Expression?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming that the names of the parameters are First and Second, then you can access the values using the following expression.

```
=Parameters!First.Value
=Parameters!Second.Value
```

You can use this type of expression for any parameter, of any type, as long as you know the name.